# Application context listener doesn't work after migrating to Spring Boot 2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have recently migrated Spring Boot from 1.5 to 2.0. After migration, when I run the application, custom context listener is called and in it if we add a property source before a source that is not yet created, then it stops the application with `exit code 1`.

With Spring Boot 1.5.x, `ConfigFileApplicationListener` adds `applicationConfigurationProperties` to list of available property source.

For some reason,  `applicationConfigurationProperties` is not getting added after migration and because of that following code fails:

```
event.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addBefore("applicationConfigurationProperties", new MapPropertySource("aws", parameters));
```

With Spring 1.5.x

```
o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment:Adding PropertySource 'aws' with search precedence immediately higher than 'applicationConfigurationProperties'
```

I enabled the following logs as well but don't see any exception:

```
logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.context=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.boot=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.core=TRACE
```

All application listeners implement `ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent>`. 
I checked the migration guide and found that a new event is added, [ApplicationStartedEvent](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#spring-boot-application-events-changes) but that should not make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no property source named `applicationConfigurationProperties` in Spring Boot 2. The names of property sources derived from a configuration file now include details of where the file was found. For example, if you have an `application.properties` file at the root of the classpath, you will have a property source named `applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]`.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out the hard way. I fixed the code by adding property source after `RandomValuePropertySource.RANDOM_PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME` instead of before `ConfigFileApplicationListener.APPLICATION_CONFIGURATION_PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME`. I wonder why Spring team made this change. By the way, they forgot to remove that constant from `ConfigFileApplicationListener`.

Comment: Including the location from which the properties were loaded in the source's name makes things like the Acuator's `/env` endpoint much more useful. Thanks for the pointer to the old constant. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13836) to deprecate it.